# Form data cannot be received by the laravel server

Tags: php, laravel, inertiajs, laravel-10

I'm encountering an issue when using Inertia's form helper to submit forms that include file inputs, specifically for updating entries. When updating text fields, the data is successfully sent to the server and returned as expected. However, when a file input is changed and the form is submitted, the server receives an empty array instead of the updated data. This issue only occurs when the file input is modified. Text inputs update correctly without issue.

Here's the relevant frontend code:

```js
const { data, setData, post, put, patch, errors, processing, clearErrors, reset } = useForm({
    // ...
})

const submit = () => {
    console.log(data);

    if (type == "create")
        return post(route("logs.store"), { onError: (e) => console.dir(e) })

    // I've tried both put and patch
    patch(route("logs.update", log?.id), {
        onError: (e) => console.dir(e)
    })
}
```

And the corresponding controller methods:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    return $request;
}

public function update(Request $request, DayLog $log)
{
    return $request;
}
```

The server response is as follows:

When images are not changed: `[{ // data }]`
When images are changed: `[]`

The console log of the data before the PUT method is:

```js
Object { id: "9b66ee2d-2ad4-47bb-a365-55bd82514cde", date: "2024-02-14", work: "sfd", in: "04:34:00", out: "04:43:00", note: null, payment_method: null, expenses: [], images: FileList(1) }
{
...
id: "9b66ee2d-2ad4-47bb-a365-55bd82514cde"
images: FileList [ File ]
0: File { name: "icon-bg_2.jpg", lastModified: 1699343241488, size: 69276, … }
length: 1
<prototype>: FileListPrototype { item: item(), length: Getter, … }
...
}
```

Any assistance or insights into why this might be happening would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In your JavaScript code, when you console log data before sending the request, you can see that the images property contains a FileList object, which represents the selected files from the file input. However, Inertia does not handle FileList objects I think, so you can try something like this

```
const submit = () => {
    // Clone the data object to avoid modifying the original
    const formData = { ...data };

    // If there are selected files, extract the first file from the FileList
    if (formData.images && formData.images.length > 0) {
        formData.images = formData.images[0];
    }

    console.log(formData);

    if (type == "create")
        return post(route("logs.store"), { data: formData, onError: (e) => console.dir(e) });

    // Use put or patch based on your requirements
    return patch(route("logs.update", log?.id), { data: formData, onError: (e) => console.dir(e) });
}
```